# vba - copy into a merged cell is not working

Tags: vba, excel

For my userform I have found a very useful code from this site https://www.contextures.com/exceldataentryupdateform.html
which includes different functionalities such as retrieval of exisiting data entries. With some small adaptations, the code has worked perfectly - up to the point where I used merged cell in order to make the userform more "compact".

Original Code (Contextures):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim historyWks As Worksheet
Dim inputWks As Worksheet
Dim rngA As Range
Dim rngDE As Range

Dim lRec As Long
Dim lRecRow As Long
Dim lLastRec As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lCellsDE As Long
Dim lColHist As Long

Set rngA = ActiveCell
Set inputWks = Worksheets("Input")
Set historyWks = Worksheets("PartsData")
Set rngDE = inputWks.Range("OrderEntry")
lCellsDE = rngDE.Cells.Count
lColHist = 3 'order data to copy starts in this column on data sheet

  Application.EnableEvents = False

Select Case Target.Address
  Case Me.Range("OrderSel").Address
    Me.Range("CurrRec").Value = Me.Range("SelRec").Value
  Case Me.Range("OrderID").Address
    If Range("CheckID") = True Then
      Me.Range("OrderSel").Value = Me.Range("OrderID").Value
      Me.Range("CurrRec").Value = Me.Range("SelRec").Value
    Else
      Me.Range("OrderSel").ClearContents
      Me.Range("CurrRec").Value = 0
    End If
  Case Else
    GoTo exitHandler
End Select


  With historyWks
      lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row - 1
      lLastRec = lastRow - 1
  End With

  With historyWks
      lRec = inputWks.Range("CurrRec").Value
      If lRec > 0 And lRec <= lLastRec Then
        lRecRow = lRec + 1
        .Range(.Cells(lRecRow, lColHist), .Cells(lRecRow, lCellsDE)).Copy
        rngDE.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        rngA.Select
    End If
  End With


exitHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

My Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim historyWks As Worksheet  '"All Entries" Worksheet
Dim inputWks As Worksheet    '"Userform" Worksheet
Dim rngA As Range
Dim rngDE As Range

Dim lRec As Long
Dim lRecRow As Long
Dim lLastRec As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

Set inputWks = Worksheets("Userform")
Set historyWks = Worksheets("All Entries")
Set rngA = inputWks.Range("UserSel")

Application.EnableEvents = False

Select Case Target.Address
  Case Me.Range("UserSel").Address
    Me.Range("CurrRec").Value = Me.Range("SelRec").Value
  Case Me.Range("Form_UserID").Address
    If Range("CheckID") = True Then
      Me.Range("UserSel").Value = Me.Range("Form_UserID").Value
      Me.Range("CurrRec").Value = Me.Range("SelRec").Value
    Else
      Me.Range("UserSel").ClearContents
      Me.Range("CurrRec").Value = 0
    End If
  Case Else
    GoTo exitHandler
End Select

  With historyWks
      lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row - 1
      lLastRec = lastRow - 2
  End With

   With historyWks
      lRec = inputWks.Range("CurrRec").Value
      If lRec > 0 And lRec <= lLastRec Then
        lRecRow = lRec + 2
     .Range(.Cells(lRecRow, 2), .Cells(lRecRow, 2)).Copy
    inputWks.Range("Form_UserID").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=False
     .Range(.Cells(lRecRow, 3), .Cells(lRecRow, 3)).Copy
    inputWks.Range("Form_LastName").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=False
     .Range(.Cells(lRecRow, 4), .Cells(lRecRow, 4)).Copy
    inputWks.Range("Form_FirstName").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=False
     .Range(.Cells(lRecRow, 5), .Cells(lRecRow, 5)).Copy
    inputWks.Range("Form_Address").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=False
     .Range(.Cells(lRecRow, 6), .Cells(lRecRow, 6)).Copy
    inputWks.Range("Form_Citizenship").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=False
        rngA.Select
    End If
  End With

exitHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Now, it gives me the error message: "To do this, all the merged cells need to be the same size."

I also tried...

```
     .Range(.Cells(lRecRow, 2), .Cells(lRecRow, 2)).Value = inputWks.Range("Form_UserID").Value
     .Range(.Cells(lRecRow, 3), .Cells(lRecRow, 3)).Value = inputWks.Range("Form_LastName").Value
     .Range(.Cells(lRecRow, 4), .Cells(lRecRow, 4)).Value = inputWks.Range("Form_FirstName").Value
     .Range(.Cells(lRecRow, 5), .Cells(lRecRow, 5)).Value = inputWks.Range("Form_Address").Value
     .Range(.Cells(lRecRow, 6), .Cells(lRecRow, 6)).Value = inputWks.Range("Form_Citizenship").Value
```

... which doesn't work either.

Comment: Try lines like: `.Cells(lRecRow, 2).Value = inputWks.Range("Form_UserID").Value`. Copy/pasting like this is bound to fail with merged cells. But most of the time you won't even need to use copy/paste. Is this a requirement for you? If not, then don't! It also slows down your code.

Comment: Hi JvdV, I tested your code and unfortunately, I doesn't work. Moreover, it changes the old data entries...

Comment: I should have been more clear on my first comment, `Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).value = Sheets(2).Cells(1,1).value` as a theoretic way to "transfer" data would work just fine. In your case; what is `"Form_UserID"` as a range object? Furthermore, what is your definition of a `Userform`?

Comment: Form_UserID is the (merged cell) where users have to select their UserID from a dropdown list.  Users have two options how to retrieve their information: A) by selecting the their UserID in cell Form_UserID or B) by using navigation buttons.

Comment: For a better a understanding, please see contextures.com/exceldataentryupdateform.html. I did almost the exact same thing, except that that my userform has non-adjacent (and merged) cells.

Answer (score 3):

Merged cells are evil! Try to avoid them by using the *"Center Across Selection"* text alignment from the menu *"Format Cells -> Alignment"*:

- Select a range of cells in a single row (as you would when merging cells).
- Right-Click > Format Cells (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut)
- Click the Alignment tab
- Click the Horizontal drop down arrow and select "Center Across Selection"
- Click OK.

See: [Stop merging cells!](https://accessanalytic.com.au/stop-merging-cells/)

Comment: I upvoted for the phrase "*merged cells are evil*" alone.. (but a nice answer regardlesss)!

Comment: Thanks, PEH! From a technical point of view, this could indeed solve my problem. Nevertheless, there are a couple of painpoints. What if the useform is empty, how does the user know where to enter his information? And what about longer text fields?

Comment: @NKAR Probably you misuse a worksheet as UserForm? Change to a real VBA UserForm and you won't have this issues. Or recognize the merged cells in your VBA code (make sure the source range and destination range is exactly the same size when you copy it).

Comment: @NKAR there is always a possibility, but you will run into the same issues with merged cells I think.